# Could not match the date with time using PHP

Tags: php, date

I need to match(= or > ) the date with today's date and the current hour is matched with user defined value using PHP. I am explaining my code below.

```
<?php
$cdate='2018-08-27 00:00:00';
$today=date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
$cdate1=strtotime($cdate);
$today1=strtotime($today1);
if ($today1 > $cdate1) {
    echo 'greater day';
}else{
    echo 'lesser day';
}
?>
```

The above code is not working as expected. Here my requirement is to compare

1)the today's date is equal to or greater than the defined date

2)the defined hour is equal to the user-defined hour.

Comment: whats the point of `$today=date("Y-m-d h:i:s");` and `$today1=strtotime($today1);` when you can just use `time()`?

Comment: Are you sure you want `$today=date("Y-m-d h:i:s");`? `h` is 12-hour format and without `am` or `pm` this seems quite useless

Comment: @kerbholz : its 24 hour format.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php -> "h 12-hour format of an hour with leading zeros 01 through 12" and "H 24-hour format of an hour with leading zeros 00 through 23"

Comment: `H` is 24-hour format, `h` is 12-hour format

Comment: in `strtotime` function the `$today1` variable is undefined...

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTime::createFromFormat to compare date and then time.

Try:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC'); // It is important to set same timezone as the input date for comparison

$currentDateTime = new DateTime(); // current DateTime object

$cdate='2018-08-29 07:50:59'; // input date
$cdateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i:s'; // input date format

$cdateDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat($cdateFormat, $cdate);

$dateFormat = 'Y-m-d'; //only date format
$cdateOnlyDate = $cdateDateTime->format($dateFormat);
$currentDateTimeOnlyDate = $currentDateTime->format($dateFormat);


if ($currentDateTimeOnlyDate < $cdateOnlyDate) {
    echo "lesser date";
} elseif ($currentDateTimeOnlyDate > $cdateOnlyDate) {
    echo "greater date";
} else {
    echo "same date ";

    $timeFormat = 'H:i:s'; //only time format
    $currentDateTimeOnlyTime = $currentDateTime->format($timeFormat);
    $cdateOnlyTime = $cdateDateTime->format($timeFormat);
    echo "<br /> Check the var_dump below to ensure correct time w.r.t timezone<br />";
    var_dump($currentDateTimeOnlyTime, $cdateOnlyTime);
    echo "<br />";
    if ($currentDateTimeOnlyTime < $cdateOnlyTime) {
        echo "lesser time";
    } elseif ($currentDateTimeOnlyTime > $cdateOnlyTime) {
        echo "greater time";
    } else {
        echo "same time ";
    }
}
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/Oe6b3

Comment: I also compare the hour with the current hour.

Comment: You can check if `$cdate='2018-08-29 00:00:00';` its also showing `greater day'`.

Comment: The complete corrected code with time comparison is on the way. checking... will be posting soon...

Comment: @subhra, check now.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work

```
<?php
    echo var_dump($date = getdate());
      if($date['year'] >= $user_year_value && $date['mon'] >= $user_month_value && $date['mday'] >= $user_day_value){
          //** Do something. DOn't forget to set timezone */
      }

?>
```

SQL can do that for you too
getdate(); will also give you hour and minutes.

But really, SQL does the job if you're planning on using this for appointments or events.

Answer (score 0):

There is issue of

```
$today1=strtotime($today1);
```

$today1 is not define variable so change as following

```
$today1=strtotime($today);
```

then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do it simpler by using [`DateTime` objects](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)?

Additional: [Relative terms](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) for `strtotime`, `DateTime` and `date_create`.

I've quickly created some examples with some comments for you.

```
<?php

$today = new DateTime('today'); // comes with today's date and 00:00:00 for time
$now = new DateTime('now');     // comes with today's date and current time

if ($now > $today) {
    echo 'Now is later than the day\'s start... <br />';
}

echo  '<hr />';

$testDates = [
    '2018-08-07',
    '2018-08-31',
];

// Compare with "now" -> ignores time
foreach ($testDates as $testDate) {
    // Create new DateTime based on given string and sets time to 00:00:00
    $testDate = (new DateTime($testDate))->setTime(0, 0, 0);

    if ($testDate > $today) {
        echo 'Test date "' . $testDate->format('Y-m-d') . '" is greater than today: ' . $today->format('Y-m-d') . '<br />';
    }
}

echo  '<hr />';

$testDatesWithTime = [
    '2018-08-07 12:33:33',
    '2018-08-29 08:00:00', // Today - has already been
    '2018-08-29 22:00:00', // Today - is yet to come
    '2018-08-30 22:00:00',
];

// Compare with "now" -> take time into account
foreach ($testDatesWithTime as $testDate) {
    // Create new DateTime based on given string and sets time
    $testDate = new DateTime($testDate);

    if ($testDate > $now) {
        echo 'Test date "' . $testDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '" is greater than today: ' . $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '<br />';
    }
}
```

Output from above:

```
Now is later than the day's start...
```

---

```
Test date "2018-08-31" is greater than today: 2018-08-29
```

---

```
Test date "2018-08-29 22:00:00" is greater than today: 2018-08-29 09:55:06
Test date "2018-08-30 22:00:00" is greater than today: 2018-08-29 09:55:06
```

Comment: I have only `2018-08-29 00:00:00` format is user deined date time. My requirement is to calculate its equal/lesser than the todays date and whatever the hour mention here is matched the current hour or not.

Comment: If the user defined date & time are in `Y-m-d H:i:s` format, then you can use it in the second loop, compared vs the `new DateTime('now')`.

Comment: `$cdate='2018-08-29 00:00:00';
$now = new DateTime('now');
$testDate = new DateTime($cdate);
if ($testDate > $now) {
    echo 'Test date "' . $testDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '" is greater than today: ' . $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . '<br />';
}else if ($testDate == $now) {
 echo "equal";
}else{
 echo 0;
}`. Its printing 0 as output.

Comment: Where my above code should print `equal`. and my other point also user will match that given time hour is the current hour or not.

Comment: It should not print equal. It's doing what it should. Unless you meant to compare with `new DateTime('today')` (note the use of *today* instead of *now*). "today" has 00:00:00 for time, "now" has the current time.

Comment: Added link to Relative terms at top of answer. Has explanations for terms such as "today", "now", "midnight", etc.

Answer (score 0):

- The first problem has already been mentioned several times: $today1
  is undefined
- The second problem is using h in the time-format: it  will never work out that way
- Furthermore with a date format like the
  one you are using, which are well ordered, string comparison order is
  identical to chronological order. So there is no need to convert to a
  time object.

This version does of course not only compare the hour but also the minutes and seconds, if that is a problem simply cut the strings.

```
<?php
$cdate='2018-08-29 10:00:00';
$today=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

if ($today > $cdate) {
    echo 'greater day';
} else {
    echo 'lesser day';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually  need a function for this but it just in order to make test more than once:

```
function compareDate($cdate){
    $today=date("Y-m-d h:i:s");
    $cdate=array_chunk(date_parse($cdate),3,true);//use date parse to handle any valid date format
    $today=array_chunk(date_parse($today),3,true);
    $cday=join('-',$cdate[0]);//get only the day without the time
    $thisday=join('-',$today[0]);
    $cHour=$cdate[1]['hour'];//get only the hour as it is the OP requirement
    $thishour=$today[1]['hour'];
    if ($thisday > $cday)
    {
        echo '<br>greater day<br>';
    }
    elseif($thisday == $cday)//if this day == user defined date compare only Hour then
    {
        echo '<br>same day<br>';
        if ($thishour > $cHour)
        {
            echo '<br>greater hour<br>';
        }
        elseif($thishour == $cHour)
        {
            echo '<br>same hour<br>';
        }else
        {
            echo '<br>lesser hour<br>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<br>lesser day<br>';
    }
}
compareDate('2018-08-27 00:00:00');
```

output:

```
greater day
```

then

```
compareDate(date("Y-m-d h:i:s"));
```

output:

```
same day 
same hour
```